# Generar gráfico Boxplot con Matplotlib - Python 3.6

Tags: python, matplotlib

Me gustaría generar un gráfico de tipo boxplot como el siguiente ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bien pues este es el gráfico y estos son los datos (que también adjunto):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se generaran 2 gráficos, uno para la columna 'count' y otro para la columna 'count2'. Quiero que para cada posible valor de la columna 'valor' haya una columna, en este caso siempre habrá una columna para el 1 para el 2 y para el 3. Entonces quiero representar mediante las cajas, por ejemplo para el valor 1 su distribución con sus 'outliers', y así para los demás valores. No se me ocurre como hacerlo. Es posible lo que digo ?

[Datos de EJEMPLO](https://drive.google.com/open?id=165f53_R0UzVxKJ0_67UZq0aF5P_kbWfV)

**SOLUCIONADO**

```
#Obtiene las listas de datos de count con cada valor de la columna valor
list_1_count = df.query('valor == 1')['count'].tolist()
list_2_count = df.query('valor == 2')['count'].tolist()
list_3_count = df.query('valor == 3')['count'].tolist()
#Obtiene las listas de datos de count2 con cada valor de la columna valor
list_1_count2 = df.query('valor == 1')['count2'].tolist()
list_2_count2 = df.query('valor == 2')['count2'].tolist()
list_3_count2 = df.query('valor == 3')['count2'].tolist()
#Crea el conjunto de datos de count para generar el gráfico
data_count = [list_1_count , list_2_count , list_3_count ]
#Crea el conjunto de datos de count2 para generar el gráfico
data_count2 = [list_1_count2 , list_2_count2 , list_3_count2 ]
#Propiedades de la linea de la mediana en el grafico
medianprops = dict(linestyle='-', linewidth=1, color='black')   
#Crea los graficos
fig0, ax0 = plt.subplots()
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax0.set_title('Box Plot Count')
ax0.set_ylabel('Count')
ax0.grid(True)
box_plot0 = ax0.boxplot(data_count, patch_artist=True, medianprops=medianprops)

ax1.set_title('Box Plot Count2')
ax1.set_ylabel('Count2')
ax1.grid(True)
box_plot1 = ax1.boxplot(data_count2, patch_artist=True, medianprops=medianprops)
```

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta, quieres un boxplot para `count` y otro para el `count2`?

Comment: Si, quiero generar un grafico con 3 cajas, cada una para los conjuntos de valores de la primera columna donde coincidan que su 'valor' sea 1, 2 o 3. Y lo mismo con la segunda columna.

Comment: Sigo sin entender Alfredo, quizás si me das un ejemplo de como quedarían los datos para graficarlos te podría ayudar mejor.

Comment: Ya lo he conseguido, pero gracias de todas formas. Saludos

Comment: Postea tu solución para que otras personas puedan ver como resolviste el problema